# WildFlyDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.XADataSource

Tags: java, datasource, wildfly, jta

I use WildFly 10.1.0, latest jdk at this moment, postgreSql 9.4.

I followed these instructions https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/understanding-jta, but in my case was differences. 
I must use dependency injection, so data source comes from app server:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:/PostgresXADS")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

When i do this code in one of my dao classes (does'nt matter), dataSource already there:

```
    XADataSource xaDataSource = (XADataSource)jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
    XAConnection xaConnection = xaDataSource.getXAConnection();
    XAResource xaResource = xaConnection.getXAResource();
    Xid xid = new MyXid();
    xaResource.start(xid, XAResource.TMNOFLAGS);
    String sql = "select * from cart where customer_id=?;";
    List<Cart> lc = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] {id}, ROW_MAPPER_C);
    xaResource.end(xid, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);

    int ret = xaResource.prepare(xid);
    if (ret == XAResource.XA_OK) {
        xaResource.commit(xid, false);
    }

    return lc;
```

I must use jdbcTemplate to, but without spring framework.

And i get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.XADataSource
```

What can be wrong? And if i do all right, how convert WildFlyDataSource to XADatasource?

Comment: Please post your datasource definition from your wildfly config

Comment: Check your deployment for a library that contains a `javax.sql.XADataSource`. It looks like you may have included a library in your deployment that includes it.